# Was ist das Gegenteil von "Autodidakt"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

Gerne würde ich in einem Projekt die Kategorie "Person, die auf Basis fremder vorgegebener Inhalte und Strukturen lernt" etwas griffiger fassen, denn ihr Pendant heißt schlicht "Autodidakt".

Googeln nach "Gegenteil Autodidakt" liefert rein gar nichts, und auch wenn ich beinahe sicher bin, dass es keinen aus einem oder zwei Wörtern bestehenden Begriff gibt, der "Gegenteil von Autodidakt" bedeutet, ist eine halbwegs elegante Formulierung bestimmt zu finden.

Hat jemand einen Vorschlag?

Comment: Auch ein Autodidakt lernt auf Basis fremder vorgegebener Inhalte und Strukturen (sonst wäre er kein Autodidakt, sondern ein Forscher, oder einfach nur erfahren). Was den Autodidakten auszeichnet, ist, dass er ohne fremde *Anleitung* lernt.

Comment: Wie wär's mit schlichtweg Schüler bzw. dann mit Abschluss irgendwann mal Studierter oder Gelehrter? (Und ja, ich weiß, dass es auch sowas wie Selbststudium gibt (was aber auch vllt nur heißt, dass man nicht ständig die Hochschule besucht hat, z.b. wenn man an einer Fernuni studiert hat), aber i.d.R. bezeichnen die Begriffe jemanden, der eine Hochschule besucht hat, sprich Vorlesungen gehört hat)

Comment: Ein Gegenteil von Autodidakt zu finden ist ungefähr so, als wolle man ein Gegenteil von "rot" finden. Es gibt keine reine Dichotomie bei den Lerntypen. Viel mehr gibt es verschiedene, sodass man da nicht einfach so ein Gegenteil bestimmen kann.

Comment: @Takkat: Es gibt nur diese beiden Kategorien. Einen Pot für Menschen, die am liebsten ohne, wie celtschk treffend benennt, *Anleitung* lernen (vielleicht ohne Institution, fixe Zeiten, Lehrpläne und sonstige Einflüsse) und solche, die an Unis, in Kursen, Schulen und Workshops erfolgreicher lernen (ungeachtet dessen, dass die Übergänge fließend sind). Es kann sich gerne um grobe Begriffe handeln, die aber die Idee transportieren sollten.

Comment: @Em1: "Schüler" vs. "Autodidakt" klingt nicht griffig, schon eher "Gelehrter". Dennoch suche ich etwas noch Griffigeres.

Comment: @Hellenologophilist: was wären denn Beispiele für die verschiedenen Lerntypen, die begrifflich auf derselben Ebene wie "Autodidakt" stehen? Vielleicht passt einer...

Comment: @Olaf Ich sah *Autodidakt* immer als einen Menschen, der vor allem durch das Studium von Büchern lernt. Da gegen stehen Leute, die am ehesten durch Frontalunterricht, durch Gruppenarbeit oder nach dem Prinzip learning-by-doing lernen. Wenn man Autodidakt aber eher wie bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidakt) oder generell als "ohne äußere Anleitung lernender" definiert, dann existiert eine Dichotomie.

Comment: Griffige Begriffe gibt es dafür m.A. nach nicht. Wenn ich für die Zeitung einen Begriff suchen würde, fiele mir *Konsument von Bildungsangeboten* ein, und ich glaube, sowas auch schon gelesen zu haben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein Autodidakt ist ja nicht einfach jemand, der selbst lernt, sondern jemand, der etwas selbst erlernt, das üblicherweise von einem Lehrer gelehrt wird. So würde man von einem Schriftsteller oder Radfahrer nie sagen, er wäre Autodidakt, von einem bildenden Künstler oder Gelehrten, die üblicherweise durch eine akademische Ausbildung gehen, aber schon. Insofern ist das Gegenteil des Autodidakten **der Ausgebildete**.

Xenodidakt finde ich nicht gut, weil unverständlich. Ich kann kein Griechisch und ohne Erklärung bedeutet mir das Wort nichts. Das ist sicher nicht das Ziel des Fragestellers.

Comment: Schwierige Entscheidung, wer den Zuschlag bekommt, aber im Plural funktioniert der Gegensatz "Autodidakten" und "Ausgebildete" für die disjunkten Gruppen tatsächlich am besten. Danke.

Answer (score 5):

### **Xenodidakt**

Ein Autodidakt ist dem Sinn des Wortes nach ein Selbstlerner. Das Gegenteil wäre also ein Fremdlerner. Auf griechisch wäre das dann ein "Xenodidakt". Allerdings ist diese Wortschöpfung nicht wirklich gebräuchlich.

Comment: +1 für eine nette Wortschöpfung (0 Treffer bei Google), die es aber nicht wirklich trifft, weil "Xeno-" i. S. v. "Fremd-" eher für (z. B. kulturell) eher weiter Entferntes steht. Dennoch weist das in eine gute Richtung: vielleicht ließe sich das "Auto" auch anders ersetzen?

Comment: +1 Mir gefählt der Neologismus.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit *Exodidakt*, um das lernen durch andere hervorzuheben?

Comment: @Hellenologophilist: "Exodidakt" gefällt mir. Sieht man es neben "Autodidakt" stehen, ist die Bedeutung schon ziemlich klar.

Comment: Vielleicht "Allodidakt" (von griechisch "allo", der Andere)?

Comment: @celtschk: Auch nicht schlecht. In jedem Fall verstärkt sich die Tendenz zum ...didakt.